# Let $G$ a simple connected topological group and $H$ a normal discrete subgroup, then $\pi_1(G/H,e) = H.$

Tags: homotopy-theory, topological-groups, covering-spaces

I know that $G$ is a covering space for $G/H$ and there is a injection between the fundamental group of $G$ and $G/H.$ How to proceed to show that $\pi_1(G/H,e) = H?$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287155/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G$ is simply connected and $H$ is discrete implies the action of $H$ on $G$ induced by right translations is proper and free. This implies that $G$ is the universal cover of $G/H$ and $H$ is the group of Deck transformations of $G/H$ and $\pi_1(G/H)=H$.

Comment: thanks! Do you know any simple proof? I mean, that does not use Deck transformations and universal covering?